# http proxy behind nginx redirecting to wrong url

Tags: nginx, proxy, jupyter

I have nginx listening on a server to serve a website `www.example.com`

I'm trying to redirect `www.example.com/iPython` to an http-server which serves a temporary iPython notebook and is sitting on the server at port 8000 https://github.com/jupyterhub/configurable-http-proxy

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    charset utf-8;
    location /iPython {
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/;
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
nginx_1              | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [19/Sep/2016:16:14:09 +0000] "GET /iPythontest HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
web_1                | Not Found: /spawn/iPythontest
nginx_1              | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [19/Sep/2016:16:14:10 +0000] "GET /spawn/iPythontest HTTP/1.1" 404 9298 "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/iPythontest" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

The server then gets redirected to `http://www.example.com/spawn/iPython` rather than `http://www.example.com/iPython/spawn` which returns a 404 error on my site. I would like to make sure all traffic gets redirected in this way, but I'm not sure which directive can accomplish that

Comment: `server_name ` should be `www.example.com`, rather than `_`.
Could you please give us line from access log file?

Comment: Added some detail to the question, thanks!